# Error while using URLconf defined in mysite.urls (Django tutorial)

Tags: django, python-2.7

I know this question has been asked and i have gone through all those answers but i didn't get the solution still. Please help me find out what is wrong . 
This is the code from django website for version 1.11 of django  .

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite/polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

mysite/polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

I am getting the following error 
[Click to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihseQ.png)

Comment: Python 2 support ended on the 1st of January 2020. If you are learning Python or Django, please use Python 3. Support for Django 1.11 is ending soon, so it would be better to use Django 3.0.x or the latest 2.2.x long term support release.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your help and this information . I'll learn using the newer version next.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `urls.py` is in the wrong place, it should be `mysite/mysite/urls.py` (in the same directory as `settings.py`).